# Uploading images: 'ø' get replaced with 'Ã¸'

Tags: images, uploads, media-library

So, I have 2 sites. One in production, and the another in development.
They have the same content and uploads.

In production, images with names containing `æ`, `ø`, or `å` gets the character replaced with something else, for example `ø` get replaced with `Ã¸`, and then saved in the upload folder. And it works! Wordpress somehow gets the right image when I request it.

E.g: `wp-content/upload/2015/01/interiørtips.jpg` will display the image `interiÃ¸rtips.jpg`.

In the database, the references to the images are saved normally, including the special characters; `æøå` is used in the name, not some other obscure character combination. This means that the database is ok.

I exported all the content from production to a fresh database in development, but now every image which has either an `æ`, `ø`, or `å` in it wont load the same way as in production. The request `wp-content/upload/2015/01/interiørtips.jpg` won't load anything, but `wp-content/upload/2015/01/interiÃ¸rtips.jpg` will. This is opposite of the behavior in production.

Does anyone know anything about this?

EDIT: I'll probably just some rename tool. But, if anyone has any insights, please share.

Comment: Right. WordPress replace only a small list from strings. If your language have different strings, then is a Dropin or plugin helpful, that replace the strings on upload. Use the filter hook sanitize_file_name. See this Dropin as example https://github.com/bueltge/de_DE.php/blob/master/de_DE.php

Comment: Oh, this is a good one... Can replicate issues in my local setup and I am reasonably sure I got no bad config issues (dealing with cyrillic and such at times).

Answer (score 4):

WP `sanitize_file_name()` function doesn't handle those characters by default.

You can add filter and sanitize those to avoid encoding issues.

```
function mamaduka_sanitize_file_name( $filename ) {
    $filename = strtr($filename, 'ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöøùúûüýÿÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöøùúûüýÿĀāĂăĄąĆćĈĉĊċČčĎďĐđĒēĔĕĖėĘęĚěĜĝĞğĠġĢģĤĥĦħĨĩĪīĬĭĮįİıĲĳĴĵĶķĹĺĻļĽľĿŀŁłŃńŅņŇňŉŌōŎŏŐőŒœŔŕŖŗŘřŚśŜŝŞşŠšŢţŤťŦŧŨũŪūŬŭŮůŰűŲųŴŵŶŷŸŹźŻżŽžſƒƠơƯưǍǎǏǐǑǒǓǔǕǖǗǘǙǚǛǜǺǻǼǽǾǿ', 'SZszYAAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiinoooooouuuuyyAAAAAAAECEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYsaaaaaaaeceeeeiiiinoooooouuuuyyAaAaAaCcCcCcCcDdDdEeEeEeEeEeGgGgGgGgHhHhIiIiIiIiIiIJijJjKkLlLlLlLlllNnNnNnnOoOoOoOEoeRrRrRrSsSsSsSsTtTtTtUuUuUuUuUuUuWwYyYZzZzZzsfOoUuAaIiOoUuUuUuUuUuAaAEaeOo');

    return $filename;
}
add_filter( 'sanitize_file_name', 'mamaduka_sanitize_file_name' );
```

Code example for this trac comment - https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16330#comment:22.

Comment: If I upload a file with the name åøæ.jpg, It gets changed to UNUtUN.jpg. That doesn't seem right from what I can tell.